# solr : concat two field in one

Tags: xml, solr, field

I am working with Solr 4.3.0, and i am trying to add a new field that concats two other field in the index. 
I have added this in `solrconfig.xml` :

```
<processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
 <str name="source">session_lieu</str>
 <str name="dest">session_lieu_mois</str>
</processor> 
<processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
  <str name="source">session_mois</str> 
  <str name="dest">session_lieu_mois</str>
</processor>
<processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="fieldName">session_lieu_mois</str> 
  <str name="delimiter">_</str> 
</processor>
<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

But still dosen't work!
What else should i do ?
Thanks for your help

I added this  :

```
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <!-- See below for information on defining 
         updateRequestProcessorChains that can be used by name 
         on each Update Request
      -->
    <!--
       <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="update.chain">dedupe</str>
       </lst>
       -->

  <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">concatenation</str>
    </lst>       
  </requestHandler>
```

Comment: can you update on any other solution you got?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your `/update` hanlder in solrconfig ?

```
 <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">your chain name here</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

You would also want to check out [Deduplication](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication)

**EDIT**

Update requestHandler like below as XmlUpdateRequestHandler is deprecated.
Make sure `session_lieu_mois` **exists** as a field in your schema or else create a dynamic field by adding `_s` at the end of the field name.

```
     <requestHandler name="/update/processortest" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" >
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="update.chain">concatenation</str>
   </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```

This will create a separate request handler. To test above go the documents tab under the solr admin console.

[image: solr console]

But if you want to call the processor chain while say dataimporting you would add your processor chain under dataimport requesthandler like below

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"
    class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    <str name="update.chain">concatenation</str>
    </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

so when dataimport is called, your processor chain is also called simultaneously.

Comment: I just add it, and there's no duplication in my XML, but still not working !

Comment: can you post what you added in the solr-config.xml ? also stacktraces if any while importing in the log inside the console

Comment: I got only some warnings in my logs and nothing about the new field,
i edited the topic. Thx

Comment: @SumeetSharma Is there any way to have something like this on query time dynamically?